# jQuery: ajax inside another? smart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax call at the moment:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "misc/sendPM.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,

    success: function(stuff) {

        if (typeof stuff == "object") {
            var err = confirm(stuff.error);
            if (err) {
                alert('You pressed OK'); // MAKE AJAX CALL HERE HERE HERE HERE
            } else {
                $("#pmResponse").text("Mottagare saknas!").show().fadeOut(4500);
                $('#sendPM_btn').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#txt').attr('readonly', false);
                $('#title').attr('readonly', false);
            }
        } else {

            $(stuff).prependTo('#PrivateMessages').fadeIn(1000);
            $('#txt').val("");

            $("#pmResponse").text("Skickat!").show().fadeOut(4500);
            $('#sendPM_btn').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#txt').attr('readonly', false);
            $('#title').attr('readonly', false);
        }
    }
});
```

I am making an "Did you mean?" If the user hasn't typed in right name for the recipient. The "did you mean name" comes in a confirm, so you could press OK or Cancel -> to type again a new name.

If you press ok right now, you only get a alert (see above code). But what I want to do when you press OK is make a change in 'recipient' data name, and send back the same data. Is this possible? How?

So conclusion what I am doing now is:

> Sending request to sendPM.php with
>   data, sendPM.php grabs the data and if
>   it finds the recipient name is
>   unclear(eg. Megan F) then it returns
>   JSON "error" with: Did you mean Megan
>   Fox?, the $.ajax on success grabs it,
>   and make it as a confirm box. If you
>   press OK on the confirm box(if you did
>   mean megan fox), *then* it should send
>   back "Megan Fox" to sendPM.php along
>   with all the previous data,
>   In order to complete the process fully.

Is there a better way to do this?

If no, how can I then send back "megan fox" to sendPM.php along with the previous data in order to complete the process fully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them into functions instead.

```
function sendRequest(data) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: data
        success: process
    });
}

function process(stuff) {
    ...
    if(err && confirm("Did you mean " + stuff.suggestion + "?")) {
        sendRequest([make your new data here]);
    }
    ...        
}
```